# Querystring of HttpGet are gone in multisession MVC4 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a webapplication which should be extended to meet new requirements. One requirement ist to handle one single GET parameter.

The application is a online calculator in financial sector. So the representatives want to calculate multiple scenarios at the same time. Therefore I implemented the `GuidRoute` from http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/02/get-a-unique-session-in-each-browser-tab/#.UkVi4YZcVKU. The overriden `GetRouteData` method simply adds a GUID into the routed values.

calling url : www.example.com/calc
url after passing `GetRouteData`:  www.example.com/calc/{yourguid}
the Url pattern : "{controller}/{action}/{id}"

Now I want to receive a new HttpGet query string parameter. Most guys say: Mvc framework simple maps the params by name.

But I doesn't in my application. I extended the method signatur to `public Action DoSomething(string newGetParameter)` and called the site with www.example.com/calc?newGetParameter=foo

But the newGetParameter is always null. After some research and a little bit of try-and-error I changed the routes pattern to `"{controller}/{action}/{id}/{newGetParameter}"`. But `RouteData.Values["newGetParameter"]` is empty.

Hope someone can help me
Christian

Comment: nice that you liked my blog post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after some detail reading I recognized the url calls of other discussions. My mistake was calling www.example.com/calc?newGetParameter=foo. Instead I have to call with a slash before the ?newGetParameter=foo like this => www.example.com/calc/?newGetParameter=foo